# Customize sandpack preview loading and errors from codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preview, codesandbox

can anyone help me related to sandpack? Do you know of any way to customize the sandpack preview error? I would like to customize the sandpack preview loading but I can't find it in the documentation

https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/docs

I tried to customize using native CSS classes but I'm looking for how to do it directly through the sandpack preview package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.